# nth item in List to dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary, enumeration, python-3.5

I am trying to create a dictionary from every nth element of a list with list's original index as key. So for example:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Now running

```
dict(enumerate(l)).items()
```

gives me:

```
dict_items([(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8), (8, 9)])
```

which is what I want. However the problem begins when I want to now select every second value from l to do this, so I try

```
dict(enumerate(l[::2])).items()
```

which gives me

```
dict_items([(0, 1), (1, 3), (2, 5), (3, 7), (4, 9)])
```

but I do not want that, I want to preserve the original index when making a dictionary. What is the best way to do this?

I want the following output

```
dict_items([(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7), (8, 9)])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) on the `enumerate()` object:

```
from itertools import islice

dict(islice(enumerate(l), None, None, 2)).items()
```

`islice()` gives you a slice on any *iterator*; the above takes every second element:

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> dict(islice(enumerate(l), None, None, 2)).items()
dict_items([(0, 1), (8, 9), (2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7)])
```

(note that the output is as expected, but order is, as always, [determined by the hash table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-is-the-order-in-python-dictionaries-and-sets-arbitrary/15479974#15479974)).

Comment: This does it. Thanks. Now I will go and start reading on this function.